# Django configuration to send email on server

Tags: python, django

I really need your help. About a week I'm trying to configure mail on my server. I use nginx -> uwsgi -> django application.
The problem is that the mail server works only with the following backend:

```
class SSLEmailBackend(EmailBackend):
    def open(self):
        if self.connection:
            return False
        try:
            self.connection = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(
                self.host, self.port, local_hostname=DNS_NAME.get_fqdn())

            if self.username and self.password:
                self.connection.ehlo()
                # Remove CRAM-MD5 authentication method
                self.connection.esmtp_features['auth'] = 'PLAIN LOGIN'
                self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
            return True
        except:
            if not self.fail_silently:
                raise
```

My settings for it:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "my_app.backends.SSLEmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "mail.my_mail_server.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "host@myhost.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "my_pass"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "host@myhost.com"
```

Locally, it works completely well!

The strangest thing that a message can be sent without any errors in the server console:

```
>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>> send_mail('test email', 'hello world', '', ['my_test@gmail.com'])
```

The problem comes when I try to register a new user. I use Django-userena backend for registration. Registration is successful, but the emails come only on the server to /var/mail/user1

Text of email:

```
rom MAILER-DAEMON Sun Oct 26 02:06:01 2014
Return-path: <>
Envelope-to: webmaster@localhost
Delivery-date: Sun, 26 Oct 2014 02:06:01 +0400
Received: from Debian-exim by mail.my_mail_server.com with local (Exim 4.80)
        id 1Xi9TF-0002Wp-Ml
        for webmaster@localhost; Sun, 26 Oct 2014 02:06:01 +0400
X-Failed-Recipients: test@test.com
Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
From: Mail Delivery System <Mailer-Daemon@elib.rshu.ru>
To: webmaster@localhost
Subject: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
Message-Id: <E1Xi9TF-0002Wp-Ml@mail.my_mail_server.com>
Date: Sun, 26 Oct 2014 02:06:01 +0400
Status: O

This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  test@test.com
    Mailing to remote domains not supported
------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------
Return-path: <webmaster@localhost>
Received: from localhost ([::1] helo=mail.my_mail_server.com)
        by mail.my_mail_server.com with esmtp (Exim 4.80)
        (envelope-from <webmaster@localhost>)
        id 1Xi9TF-0002Wm-Lv
for test@test.com; Sun, 26 Oct 2014 02:06:01 +0400
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Subject: =?utf-8?b?0KDQtdCz0LjRgdGC0YDQsNGG0LjRjyDQsiDRjdC70LXQutGC0YDQvtC90L0=?=
 =?utf-8?b?0L7QuSDQsdC40LHQu9C40L7RgtC10LrQtSDQoNCT0JPQnNCj?=
From: webmaster@localhost
To: test@test.com
Date: Sat, 25 Oct 2014 22:06:01 -0000
....
```

I've been checking userena, nginx, etc. I can not understand what could be the problem. Why it works locally and on the server console messages can be sent. Please help.

Comment: I would simply suggest to you to change for a working, more trivial, email service and backend. E.g. here http://opensourcehacker.com/2013/03/26/using-postfix-and-free-mandrill-email-service-for-smtp-on-ubuntu-linux-server/

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not change the email service.

Comment: Does anybody at least approximately know what the problem could be?

Comment: at first have you cheked typos? for example `self.connection.ehlo()`

Answer (score 0):

Your mail server is not set up to accept remote mail forwarding. The error message from the server is 'Mailing to remote domains not supported.'  So, whatever mail server you are connecting to is not recognizing that your web server is a 'trusted user' who's mail should be accepted and forwarded.  I would try to get your mail service provider to whitelist your server for sending email.